# update post category in a new table on frequent change of category

Tags: posts, updates

I am creating a new voting plugin

1. I have created a table name 'wp_vote_info', it has four fields'id', 'postid', 'type_of _vote', current_category.
2. When some user vote on that particular post,i am storing the postid, and type of vote(up or down), current_category given for that post.

**Problem to be solved:**

3. For a period of time the post category may be set as ('Software') after some days or hours it may be changed to (Technology). At that case 'current_category' field should be update based upon the 'postid'.

**Note:**
(On update of post category it should also update in the New table 'wp_vote_info').

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use an Action Hook '`save_post`' to implement the requirement and this way categories will stay synced with your custom table and default tables.

Example :

```
 function post_updated_sync_category( $post_id ) {

    //Here you get postid of the post being updated
    //You can put your code to update in custom table here
}
add_action( 'save_post', 'post_updated_sync_category' );
```

You can use this hook with custom post type as well, here is how you can implement this, see [WordPress Codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/save_post)

Comment: Can i write sql query inside the above function

Comment: of course you can, you could perform anything in this function to match your requirement.

Comment: below is the code which i have used for update in the table but its not updating in the table         function post_updated_sync_category( $post_id ) {
 $postid = $_POST['postid'];
 $terms=wp_get_post_terms($postid,'product_cat' ); 
 $current_brand= $terms[0]->slug;
  global $wpdb;
    $table = $wpdb->prefix . "_vote";
 $wpdb->get_results( 'SELECT * FROM '.$table.' WHERE postid = "'.$postid.'"' );
 if($wpdb->num_rows > 0 ){
  $wpdb->query("UPDATE $table SET `currentstatus`= $current_brand WHERE `postid` = '".$postid."' ");
  }
}
add_action( 'save_post', 'post_updated_sync_category' );

Comment: why this `$postid = $_POST['postid'];` it should be just `$postid = $post_id;`